# How to restart the Timer in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, client, client-server

I am facing issues with timer control in c#. see the explanation in code,

```
Onform_Load
{ 
 // On form load initiating the timer control, to verify whether the server       connection is established or not
 timer2 = new Timer();
 timer2.Interval = 1000;
 timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
 timer2.Start();
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
   Socket sock = Sockets.CreateTCPSocket(IPAddress, Convert.ToInt32(Port));
   client = new ClientInfo(sock, false); // Don't start receiving yet
   client.OnReadBytes += new ConnectionReadBytes(ReadData);
   client.OnClose += new ConnectionClosed(OnClose);
   try
   {
       client.BeginReceive();
       OnConnected();
   }
   catch
   {
       OnClose();             
   }
}
void OnConnected()
{
  //connection established message
}
void OnClose(ClientInfo clnt)
{ 
  //Connection Closed
}
```

By using the above **timer2_Tick** event, the application is continuously hitting the server whether connection is established or not.

> Want to **stop** the timer **when connection is established**.

and

> **start** the timer **when connection is closed**.

**See below code:**

```
void OnConnected()
{
    timer2.Stop();
  //connection established message
}
void OnClose(ClientInfo clnt)
{ 
    timer2.Start();// here i tried timer2.Enabled and intiated the interval. but it is not working
  //Connection Closed
}
```

Can any one help me on this, how to start and stop the timer on condition based,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SomeUser, it is windows forms timer control

Comment: I don't see the problem. What is not working? Is the timer not restarting after calling `timer2.Start();` in `void OnClose(ClientInfo clnt)`? Have you made sure that `OnClose()` is being called?

Comment: @Benj, yes it is not restarting, OnClose event is called successfully . But timer2_Tick event is not initiating. Can you help me on this.

Comment: You are creating  a new `Socket` in every `Tick` of timer and also adding the events to the `Client` over and over again. It's not a good idea and should be corrected.

Comment: @RezaAghaei, right now i am working on that, and trying other ways of doing it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the timer2 calls as shown - start/stop are fine. Are you sure the OnClose method is being called (your call is missing parameters)?